# How to respond to Cyber Bullying?

Tags: privacy, anonymity, defense

I am trying to learn about Cyber Bullying and I was thinking that if in future I get bullied, then what I can do?

I have learned how to use Maltego, but if someone damages your reputation, then is there any option by which I can erase all that data from the Internet and build my reputation? I have read some solutions on how to prevent bullying but it was written to report bullying but reporting doesn't make any real difference.

Is there any solution where I can report these things and get to know the real identity or IP address of the bully doing this?

Comment: You don't want to know how to 'prevent' bullying, but how to 'punish' bullying.

Comment: well then i must edit ..

Comment: It isn't hard to get someone's IP, but it's not reliable evidence of identity as it can be spoofed, proxied, changed, etc. Also, -1 for "erasing data from the internet"...

Comment: I have heard and seen people or children who are bullied. Threatened, hurt, verbally abused, etc. It`s really unpleasant seeing people get hurt. "Haters will say what they want, but their hate will never stop you from chasing your dream". I suggest a safety application you could use if you are in trouble. Check this out for more info. http://safekidzone.com/#!/page_home

Comment: Shashank - worth having a read of this one over on Parenting: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/14117/316

Comment: Sir Rort Alsop at parenting also i have asked the same question but still someone else has taken up my question and just given some credits and no one tried to see my edits so what i can do ... i am just a normal person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for wiping the slate clean if someone tarnishes your reputation, you can request that websites disable the account but depending on the site they don't have to.

As for seeking revenge, don't. Be thankful that the individual exposed a character flaw. Harden yourself to the internet. When you do this, you cannot be cyber bullied.

Seeking revenge only lowers your own character even more and will probably lead to repeated escalation until one of you commits a cyber CRIME.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real answer to this question. Unless there is a crime and investigators can track the user, there is little you can do to track down real users from their online accounts.

As for deleting data from the Internet, at best you might find different services that might respond to such requests, but that is up to the individual services.